# Call Several Other Scripts Async

Tags: perl

I know there a lot of ways to do this, but because there are so many I don't know which one to choose.

What I want to accomplish:
1. Start several child scripts
2. Be able to check if they are running
3. Be able to kill them
4. I DON'T need to capture their output, and their output does not need to be displayed.

Each of these scripts is in their own file.

I haven't done scripting in a while and I'm stuck in an OOP mindset, so forgive me if I say something ridiculous.

Comment: Parallel::ForkManager

Comment: Can't you use a Unix shell for this purpose, such as `bash`?

Comment: There are other parts to the script that are much easier with the power of Perl

Answer (score 2):

```
use Parallel::ForkManager qw( );

use constant MAX_SIMUL_CHILDREN => 10;

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(MAX_SIMUL_CHILDREN);
for my $cmd (@cmds) {
   $pm->start()
      and next;

   open(STDOUT, '>', '/dev/null')
      or die($!);

   exec($cmd)
      or die($!);

   $pm->finish();  # Never reached, but that's ok.
}

$pm->wait_all_children();
```

---

Adding the following before the loop will log the PID of the children.

```
$pm->run_on_start(sub {
   my ($pid, $ident) = @_;
   print("Child $pid started.\n");
});

$pm->run_on_finish(sub {
   my ($pid, $exit_code, $ident, $exit_signal) = @_;
   if ($exit_signal)  { print("Child $pid killed by signal $exit_signal.\n"); }
   elsif ($exit_code) { print("Child $pid exited with error $exit_code.\n"); }
   else               { print("Child $pid completed successfully.\n"); }
});
```

`$ident` is the value passed to `$pm->start()`. It can be used to give a "name" to a process.

Comment: How can I check if each one is still running, and kill them?

Comment: You mean manually? `ps` and `kill` as usual. If automatically, then when?

Comment: By the way, the redirection of STDOUT is optional. You said something that hinted you might not want to see the output of the children, so I included it as a demonstration.

Comment: Okay, thanks! How can I store the PID of each for later use?

Comment: `$pm->running_procs` returns the PIDs of the active children at any moment in time, but you're probably more interested in setting up `on_start` and `on_finish` callbacks. The PID of the process that was started or reaped is passed to the callback as the first argument. See update.

Answer (score 0):

Perl and parallel don't go well together, but here are a few thoughts :

- `fork()` a few times, and manage each child independently
- Perl allows you to open filehandles to processes: `open my $fh, '-|', 'command_to_run.sh'`. You could use this and poll those handles
- Fork them to the background and store their process IDs

Comment: What is the purpose of `'-|'`? Could you give an example of forking?